# Is it possible to set parent UITabViewController properties from embedded UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I´m kinda confused when it comes to embedded views. I have created the following structure in storyboard:

```
-UITabBarViewController
   -UINavigationViewController
      -UITableViewController (MyTableViewController)
```

So to my question, is it possible to set the tab bar item properties, such as the title font, from within my custom UITableViewController (MyTableViewController)?

I have tried the following code in MyTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set tab bar item title
    [self setTitle:@"TEST"]; // This works, it sets the title of the tab bar item

    // This does not work
    [self.tabBarController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    // This does not work
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];

} // viewDidLoad
```

I know that I could create a custom MyTabBarViewController and place the code there. But it would be sweet to not have to create a new class just for that.

General question, how does embedded views work in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in one of my project. Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor] }
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.navigationController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Let me know if it does not work for you..

Hope this helps!